# Harddisk reinstalled - can data be recovered?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ubuntu-12.04, partition-recovery

We have a laptop here which had Ubuntu installed on it. When it came back we removed the old partitions, created a new one and installed Windows 7 on it. This install is still fresh. Will it be possible to restore data from the Ubuntu install? How can this be done?

Comment: Before you do **anything** else - power off the machine and remove the drive. Even when Widows is "doing nothing" it is writing temp files & potentially overwriting your old Linux data. Put the drive into an external housing and try to recover using another PC. Whether it succeeds or not, you have no learned the value of regular backups & will be doing so in future, won't you?  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely not going to get anything back, since you deleted the partitions and installed windows, you've most likely written over the space containing those previous partitions. The more you mess with a drive with deleted partitions, the higher the chances of getting rid of that data forever.

You can always try of course with [Testdisk](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_141890353969321&key=984ed3ed6aa9a69986f88d56d10e7616&libId=28fa62d5-2ea2-409a-a44a-9b0a0b200318&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tomshardware.com%2Fforum%2F291931-32-need-recover-data-deleted-partition&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cgsecurity.org%2Fwiki%2FTestDisk&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Furl%3Fsa%3Dt%26rct%3Dj%26q%3D%26esrc%3Ds%26source%3Dweb%26cd%3D1%26ved%3D0CDQQFjAA%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.tomshardware.com%252Fforum%252F291931-32-need-recover-data-deleted-partition%26ei%3DFL-SVIjYPKPasASv1oDYBQ%26usg%3DAFQjCNH8gV1WdBh-c5Zi3ijWEYKk4E8kQg%26sig2%3Dmnnh7hxSLZGaQ2pu-KiMQA%26bvm%3Dbv.82001339%2Cd.cWc&title=Need%20help%20to%20recover%20data%20from%20deleted%20partition%20-%20Hard%20Drives%20-%20Storage&txt=Testdisk), [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) or [Restoration](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_141890350440718&key=984ed3ed6aa9a69986f88d56d10e7616&libId=28fa62d5-2ea2-409a-a44a-9b0a0b200318&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tomshardware.com%2Fforum%2F291931-32-need-recover-data-deleted-partition&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.snapfiles.com%2Fget%2Frestoration.html&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Furl%3Fsa%3Dt%26rct%3Dj%26q%3D%26esrc%3Ds%26source%3Dweb%26cd%3D1%26ved%3D0CDQQFjAA%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.tomshardware.com%252Fforum%252F291931-32-need-recover-data-deleted-partition%26ei%3DFL-SVIjYPKPasASv1oDYBQ%26usg%3DAFQjCNH8gV1WdBh-c5Zi3ijWEYKk4E8kQg%26sig2%3Dmnnh7hxSLZGaQ2pu-KiMQA%26bvm%3Dbv.82001339%2Cd.cWc&title=Need%20help%20to%20recover%20data%20from%20deleted%20partition%20-%20Hard%20Drives%20-%20Storage&txt=Restoration)

Comment: I removed two partitions, created two new ones, installed Windows 7 and stopped when the user account was to be created. Now I'm running testdisk, and it shows "Linux" when doing the deep analysis. Not sure if that will result in anything, but it does find something.

Comment: You may find it, you may not, the more you play with the HDD though, the less chance you have of getting what you need. It's really hard to say.

Comment: I removed the harddisk, attached it to a desktop computer. Testdisk itself was not very useful, although interesting to know it exists. Photorec - part of Testdisk - is another story. This has recovered over 10k files by now, of which 99% will be system files and probably useless. I found several documents that do belong to the user, so it seems to work. Filename and dates are gone, but that was to be expected.